# Escaping Round bracket and equal sign in prepareStatementin java, sql.

Tags: sql, jakarta-ee, jdbc, db2

I am trying to write a sql statement to toggle the value of a varchar(5) column in a database using the following statement.

```
stmt = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE  TABLENAME  SET
                + MIDNIGHT =IF\\\\(MIDNIGHT=?,?,?\\\\)");
stmt.setString(1, "off");
stmt.setString(2, "on");
stmt.setString(3, "off");
```

but I am getting the following error:

com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-7, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=\;GHT =IF, DRIVER=3.59.81

MIDNIGHT is the name of the column whose value I am trying to toggle between 'on' and 'off'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `UPDATE TABLENAME SET MIDNIGHT = IF(MIDNIGHT='off','on','off')` run properly in DB2 itself?

Comment: Why do you think you need to escape parentheses and the equal sign in `prepareStatement()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SQL0007N - The character "" following "" is not
>   valid.
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> The specified "" is not a valid character in SQL
>   statements. The "" field indicates the 20 characters of the SQL
>   statement that preceded the character that is not valid.
>
> Federated system users: some data sources do not provide the
>   appropriate values for the "" and "" message tokens.
>   In these cases, "" and "" will have the following
>   format: ":UNKNOWN", indicating that the actual values for
>   the specified data source are unknown.
>
> The statement cannot be processed.
>
> **User Response:**
>
> Remove or replace the character that is not valid.
>
> sqlcode : -7
>
> sqlstate : 42601

Also, in your query, you cannot use IF statement by the way you use in Java.

a probable workaround for you would be to use case statement.

```
update TABLENAME  SET MIDNIGHT =
case when MIDNIGHT = ? then ?
     when MIDNIGHT = ? then ?
end;
```